# how to change text item delimiter in Keynote rich text so period and comma are not ignored (using Javascript for Automation)?

Tags: osx-yosemite, keynote, iwork, javascript-automation

**In short:**

with iWork rich text objects, breaking the text up in words goes from:

> "This... he said, is a sentence!"

to:

> ["This", "he", "said", "is", "a", "sentence"]

So: periods, comma and exclamation point have disappeared.
Similar to the [AppleScript situation](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24725), but with Javascript for Automation it is unclear to me how to set the text item delimiter (plus: I am hoping it can be simpler than in the old days).

**In detail:**

I would like to modify rich text like:

```
testing [value] units <ignore this>
>>>
also ignore this
<<<
etc.
```

The text can contain variations in size/color/weight, which should be kept.
The result should be e.g.:

```
testing 123 units
etc.
```

When I go through the words (in my case: presenter notes in Keynote), I get:

```
["testing", "value", "units", "ignore", "this", "also", "ignore", "this", "etc"]
```

instead of:

```
["testing", "[value]", "units", "<ignore", "this>", ">>>", "also", "ignore", "this", "<<<", "etc."]
```

So: characters like ., [, and > don't show up, which makes it impossible to search/replace.

To get the words, I use:

```
words = Application("Keynote").documents[0].slides[0].presenterNotes.words
```

I also tried using whose() in combination with ignoring/considering (case, hyphens, punctuation), but the result is the same.

How can I get a list of words that include the non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  Did .....words actually give you the words?
I've been trying to extract the presentationNotes and placing them in a txt file for about 2 days now, Can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: No, no progress. For your question: if you post it as a regular Stackoverflow question (and add comment here with link) then I can give you a code example that copies the presenterNotes (text only).

Comment: I did add write a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908323/extract-presentationnotes-from-keynote
thank you!!!

Comment: I have added a new question where I try to solve it with a different approach. That approach works great with TextEdit (attributeRuns), but attributeRuns does not seem to be available for Keynote. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989289/processing-richt-text-presenter-notes-in-keynote-using-javascript-for-automatio

Answer (score -1):

To get the full text of a slide's notes, use the `presenterNotes()` method:

```
note = Application("Keynote").documents[0].slides[0].presenterNotes()
```

It's not exactly intuitive for me, but it works fine.

Comment: that was not the question. The question is (after reading the notes) how to process them word by word including the "...", "<<<", etc. And specifically (see follow up question): how to process the richtext nature of them (font/color/size).